# Calculo para quantidade de painéis fotovoltaicos JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, matemática

Fiz um teste de cálculos baseado na formula deste vídeo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdFHC3gv63U

Usei o seguinte algoritmo:

```js
function simular() {
       
   var radiacao = 5.6;
   var tarifa = 0.71;
       
   var valorc = $("#valor-conta").val();
   var consumom = (valorc / tarifa);
       
   var paineis = ((consumom * 1000) / 30); // consumo diario
   paineis = ((paineis * 0.86) / radiacao); // eficiencia / radiacao
   paineis = parseFloat(paineis.toFixed(1)).toFixed(3); // ajusta o resultado
    
   $("#quantidade-paineis").val(Math.ceil(paineis / 330)); // quantidade de placas de 330w nescessárias
       
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="valor-conta" value="100" />
<input type="text" id="quantidade-paineis" value="0" />
<button onClick="simular()"> Simular </button>
```

O resultado funciona mas ao comparar com outros simuladores existentes ele modifica o resultado de quantidade de placas, não sei o calculo certo, se os simuladores estão calculando errado, ou o meu código não segue o padrão correto.

LINK Simulador: https://portalsolar.com.br/calculo-solar/iframe

Comment: Bom cara, não sei como é realizado estes cálculos ao certo, mas, o código já dá erro logo de cara, pois você está chamando elementos que para a **jQuery** não existem como **`$("valor-conta").val();`** e **`$("quantidade-paineis")`**. Fora também outros erros como **`$("quantidade-paineis").val() = Math.ceil(paineis / 330);`**, que não existe em jQuery, quando o correto seria **`$("quantidade-paineis").val(Math.ceil(paineis / 330));`**

Comment: Sim é que fiz um esboço no caso ele pegar o valor da conta, exemplo 100 reais ele divide pela tarifa que retorna no caso o consumo mensal em kWh, que tem que ser multiplicado por 1000 para ter em base seu valor de wats, dividindo por 30 dias que não é bem todos os meses que tem 30, outros tem 31, é só simulador, o código eu fiz agora não copiei o do projeto, mas vou colocar com o HTML junto ja vou editar ele, obrigado amigo.